# nested css grid child element expands/moves out of container

Tags: css, css-grid

https://codepen.io/1gconf/pen/zYwOegY
Hello, im trying to make a grid layout containting 6 links to projects. Each link consists of 2 rows: one is an image template the other is **texted description** underneath it. The parent for each of the 6 templates is set to `grid-template-rows:0.7fr .3fr;` **but the problem occurs with the texted description element**: it moves out of the container. Can anyone tell me why? Any help is much appreciated thx (:

```
<style>
.projects-section{
  background:var(--main-blue);
  display:grid;
  padding:7rem 2rem;
}
.projects-section-header{
  align-self:start;
  max-width:800px;
  color:var(--main-white);
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:.5rem solid var(--main-white);
  margin: 6rem auto;
}
.tilescontainer{
  justify-self:center;
  width:70%;
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2,300px) 75px;
}
.project-tile{
  border:1px solid white;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
  grid-template-rows:0.7fr .3fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "tiletemplate"
    "tiletitle"
}
.title-bg{
  grid-area:tiletitle;
  background-color:var(--main-gray);
  width:100%;
  opacity:0.85;
}
.tile-image{
  width:100%;
  height:70%;
}
.tile-title{
    color:var(--main-white);
  text-transform:capitalize;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:smaller;
}
#showallcontainer{
  grid-column:2/3;
  grid-row:3/4;
  display:grid;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
}
.showall{
  background:var(--main-gray);
  padding:0.5rem 2.5rem;
  opacity:0.85;
}
</style>
<body>
  <section id="projects" class="projects-section">
    <h2 class="projects-section-header">These are some of my projects</h2>
    <div class="tilescontainer">
      <div class="project-tile">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="dr norman borlaug" class="tile-image">
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">tribute page</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" alt="quotes" class="tile-image">
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">random quote machine</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/calc.png" alt="javascript calculator" class="tile-image">
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">javascript calculator</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="mp data" class="tile-image">
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">map data across the globe</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="wikiviewer" class="tile-image">
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">wikipedia viewer</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tic-tac-toe.png" alt="tictactoe" class="tile-image">
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">tic tac toe game</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="showallcontainer">
        <h4 class="tile-title showall">show all <i>></i></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing good effort to use grid but you give some wrong css to the parent of **project-tile** class.

```
.tilescontainer {
justify-self: center;
width: 70%;
display: grid;
grid-gap: 20px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2,300px) 75px;
```

}

correct this **grid-template-rows: repeat(2,300px) 75px;**

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of simple changes to your HTML and css.

First is I have put all images within a wrapper. That way you can set the grid sizing against the wrapper and set image height and with to 100% which would fit the wrapper size.

Next I changed your 0.7fr 0.3fr to 2fr and 1fr. Just a clearer way of setting sizing.

II used your codepen to do this and the text does not break out.

```css
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-
    }
:root {
    --main-white: #f0f0f0;
    --main-red: #be3144;
    --main-blue: #45567d;
    --main-gray: #303841;
}
h1, h2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:2.9rem;
}
body{
  line-height:1.4;
  font-size:1.8rem;
  font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.navbar{
  width:100%;
  height:75px;
  display:grid;
  justify-content:end;
  align-content:center;
  background:var(--main-red);
  padding:5px;
  /*position:fixed;*/
}
.navul{
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  margin-right:2rem;
}
.navbar ul li{
  margin:0 15px;
}
.navbar ul a{
  /*fonts*/
  font-weight:normal;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:var(--main-white);
}
.welcome-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image:linear-gradient(62deg,#3a3d40 0%,#181719 100%);
  display:grid;
  align-content:center;
  justify-items:center;
}
#welcome-title{
  text-transform:Capitalize;
  color:var(--main-white);
  font-size:3.7rem;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#welcome-text{
  text-transform:lowercase;
  color:var(--main-red);
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight:200;
  opacity:.7;
}
.projects-section{
  background:var(--main-blue);
  display:grid;
  padding:7rem 2rem;
}
.projects-section-header{
  align-self:start;
  max-width:800px;
  color:var(--main-white);
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:.5rem solid var(--main-white);
  margin: 6rem auto;
}
.tilescontainer{
  justify-self:center;
  width:70%;
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2,300px) 75px;
}
.project-tile{
  border:1px solid white;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
  grid-template-rows:2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "tiletemplate"
    "tiletitle"
}
.title-bg{
  grid-area:tiletitle;
  background-color:var(--main-gray);
  width:100%;
  opacity:0.85;
}
.tile-image{
  width:100%;
  height:70%;
}
.tile-title{
    color:var(--main-white);
  text-transform:capitalize;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:smaller;
}
#showallcontainer{
  grid-column:2/3;
  grid-row:3/4;
  display:grid;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
}
.showall{
  background:var(--main-gray);
  padding:0.5rem 2.5rem;
  opacity:0.85;
}
```

```html
 <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <ul class="navul">
      <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
    <h1 id="welcome-title">Hey i am Igor</h1>
    <p id="welcome-text">A web developer</p>
  </section>
  <section id="projects" class="projects-section">
    <h2 class="projects-section-header">These are some of my projects</h2>
    <div class="tilescontainer">
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="dr norman borlaug" class="tile-image">
        </div>
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">tribute page</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" alt="quotes" class="tile-image"></div>
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">random quote machine</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/calc.png" alt="javascript calculator" class="tile-image"></div>
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">javascript calculator</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="mp data" class="tile-image"></div>
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">map data across the globe</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="wikiviewer" class="tile-image"></div>
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">wikipedia viewer</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tic-tac-toe.png" alt="tictactoe" class="tile-image"></div>
        <div class="title-bg">
          <h4 class="tile-title">tic tac toe game</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="showallcontainer">
        <h4 class="tile-title showall">show all <i>></i></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: That solved it! I'd already tried setting the image height to 100% before, but then it took the entire height of the container in. So yeah, looks like the <img> needs a div wrapper for grid mode (: Many thanks Liam